# How can I use an online code compiler's output through in a code compiler app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I want to make an app which compiles Swift code, so how can I use a website named [www.swiftstub.com](http://www.swiftstub.com) or any similar website to retrieve the output of the code? I want my app to have a simple `UITextView` in which the user can type the code. **If** a `UITextView` cannot be used, what can be used?

I want my app to send the code typed to this website, and then retrieve the output back and display it. How can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I don't know what to do. I am a beginner @pintxo

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an app that sends text to a server.
2. Have the server compile this code, run it, and capture the output.
3. Send this output back to the app.
4. Have the app display the output.

This is an extreme oversimplification, there are lots of things to consider, but these are kind of the big sections of whats there to to. You need to understand very well on the app side: UI and networking, and on the server side: triggering a compilation of text, capturing that output (command line, maybe Swift or Python can help you here) and HTTP(S) responses and requests (or sockets, even harder).

This does not sound like an easy task, so you are very courageous.

Comment: What all do I have to learn to be able to implement this? @Joride

Answer (score 0):

Build all components locally:
App:
- write an app with a textView and a button, and on the tap of that button, save the output to a textile. This is to avoid any networking complications at this point, later, instead of saving, you would send this to a server.

Server: (just build the things on your computer)
- write some script/program that can read in that textfile that was saved.
- Then you need to compile this code (lookup 'xcrun' on google) and capture the output. Save this output to a textile. Have your app load this file and display it.
The important thing to consider is the real server machine you will run this code on later: it has to be a machine that can compile, and execute Swift code. Currently, this means it has to be an OS X machine. This is hard to find, as most servers run linux, and there is no Linux Swift compiler yet.

Getting this to work would be a proof of concept: you can capture text from the app, you can grab this text and compile it, you can capture the output of the compilation, and you can have the app read that output and display it.

Once you've got this working, you would need to find a server that can do the compilation part, and run what you build to do that. Then you would need to write some code in your app that sends an HTTP request to your server containing this text, to which your server would respond with the output of that compilation.

As I said, this is a big undertaking, with lots of difficult parts and unexpected surprises, so don't expect this to be done in a couple of weeks, it will most likely be more like over six months.
Try to find someone who has experience on programming and setting up a server, that will really help you a lot.